# Is there a way to put two labelled equations into one \begin{equation} and align both of them at the beginning?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I can't believe how difficult it is to work with `\begin{equation}`. I put one extra blank row under the equation and multiple errors popped up. Anyways, I have two equations which are labelled:

```
\begin{equation}
a = b + c  \label{1} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
ddddddd = e+x \label{2} 
\end{equation}
```

which gives

[image]

Questions:

1. Is it possible to work with just one `\begin{equation}`. I attempted to put both equations into one `\begin{equation}` and it threw me an error.

   Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '1' will be lost.
   ddddddd = e+x \label
2. Is it possible to align the equations at the beginning so that $a$ and $d$ matches up? I tried using `\begin{align}` around the code and it gave me.

   > Bad math environment delimiter. \end{align} You can't use \eqno in math mode. \end{align} Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{align} Missing
   >   } inserted. \end{align} \begin{align} on input line 445 end...

And 20 more errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write this, after you've loaded `amsmath`:

```
\begin{align}
& a = b + c  \label{1} \\
& ddddddd = e+x \label{2} 
\end{align}
```

Comment: You missed \\ after the label{1} but everything worked

Comment: Thank you for pointing the oversight. It's corrected now.

Comment: Might also want to align the `=` (just a comment to the OP)